# My PIR sensor seems alittle keen to sense things

Tags: python, pi-2, rpi.gpio, sensor

Before you tell me answers for my issue already exist I'd like to mention that I have checked previous answers and where similar issues have occurred I have tried to use their approved answer. So far no luck.

Ok, so I got a cheap PIR sensor set it up as all the instructables tutorials told me to do. Copy + paste the script. The usual (making sure my pin was the correct one used in the python script, using GPIO 7 at the moment), just to see if it would work.

**Problem:**
1. Everytime I run the script there are no errors however it instantaneously registers detection.

**Attempted Solutions**
1. To start with I thought it was maybe too sensitive so turned the sensitivity of the sensor anticlockwise in a hope to lower it.
2. Next I tried using different pins, moved from pin 4 to 7, no difference.
3. Next I thought I would try eliminate any possible movement or heat source so moved the sensor into a cool drawer and when run again the same issue is occurring.

Is their something which I am missing? Do I have a faulty sensor?

Heres what I got:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
PIR_PIN = 7

GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN)

print("Setup complete...")
print("Starting script")

try:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
            print("Motion Detected")
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Quitting")
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

All I get out is:
"Motion detected"
"Motion detected"
"Motion detected"
"Motion detected"
"Motion detected"
"Motion detected"

Untill I interrupt program.

Edit: I have been asked to show setup so images below added.

[image: PIR sensor setup]

Comment: What happens when you use pull down resistor? GPIO.setup(PIR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

Comment: `however their contexts do not apply` why not?

Comment: We need a photo of the connections you have made.  I do not trust narratives or pointers to tutorial or diagrams which may or may not have been followed correctly.

Comment: @Sebraponi I have tried what you suggested and sadly no further luck. It still continuously prints Motion Detected even when placed in an isolated environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, PIR sensors are very sensitive. When you first activate your script, you should add a 30-45 second delay at the beginning to wait for the pir to initialize itself - to "learn" its environment. During that delay, move out of the room or at least move away from the pir sensor(you can also cover the pir sensor up with something) and *don't move* until the 30-45 seconds is up. When you start your program or plug the pir in, it will most likely activate for a few seconds, then, once it is used to its (non-moving) environment, it should deactivate and start working properly.

Second, notice the yellow jumper on the corner of your pir: this sets the trigger mode for the pir. You can read about [the different trigger modes here](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-pir-sensor-works-and-how-to-use-it-with-arduino/), but I find that my pir works better in "repeatable trigger" mode, which is *not* the mode you have yours set at.

Lastly, make sure you have your delay time set as low as it can go: adjust **both** potentiometers(the orange knob things, sensitivity and delay) fully counter-clockwise.

I hope this helps you figure out your pir. I recommend reading [this article](https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/how-pir-sensor-works-and-how-to-use-it-with-arduino/) to help you understand PIRs.

ps. I would change a part of your script to read

```
if GPIO.input(PIR_PIN):
    print("Motion Detected")
else:
    print("NO MOTION")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I dont have enough rep yet to upvote but this is what I was looking for so thank you, problem fixed

Comment: @Nathaniel , even if you can't upvote this answer, you can accept it, which is like saying "this is the best answer I got and this answer solved my problem". You can accept answers by clicking the check mark right below the downvote button. Thankyou!